# Script with Oracle DROP TABLE in 11gR2

Tags: sql, oracle, drop-table

I am little bit confused about my query. I am getting error but it works.
I am using ORACLE 11gR2 in command prompt.
I have created 2 tables dp (department) and em (employee) with Primary key and foreign key.
If I run the script couple of times, the DROP TABLE function attempts to drop the table 2 times but it should try only once. Could you please give me any idea of why it is happening. My script is given below.

```
cl scr

DROP TABLE dp CASCADE CONSTRAINT ;
L
// DROP TABLE dp PURGE ;
L
CREATE TABLE dp (
    dpid    NUMBER(2),
    dname   VARCHAR2(20));

DROP TABLE em PURGE ;
CREATE TABLE em (
    emid    NUMBER(2),
    ename   VARCHAR2(20),
    dpid    NUMBER(2));

ALTER TABLE dp
ADD CONSTRAINT pk_dp_dpid PRIMARY KEY (dpid) ;

ALTER TABLE em
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_em_dp_dpid FOREIGN KEY (dpid)
REFERENCES dp (dpid) ;
```

Comment: Hi Mat, I have used a script to run those commands in command prompt. In command prompt, if i run script it shows only the result. So I have used 'L' so that it shows what it is reading here. (L shows the lines it just executed.)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using `L` to print lines after they're run, use `set echo on` at the top of your script.

`//` is not a comment marker in SQL*Plus, quite the contrary: `/` re-executes the previous command you entered (and apparently what comes after it is ignored). So your script re-executes the first drop.

Use `--` for comments.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried this (--) way. But it is still trying to drop twice. is there any way that i can send you a screenshot ?

Comment: Update your question with your updated script & the exact output you're getting.

Comment: It happened because I wrote 'L' twice.

Answer (score 0):

It was a silly mistake and my misunderstanding. ORACLE did not attempt to DROP twice. It dropped only once (as it should be) but in the script I wrote 'L' twice so it was showing the attempt twice. Anyway, the updated codes are given below.

cl scr

```
DROP TABLE dp CASCADE CONSTRAINT ;
L
CREATE TABLE dp (
    dpid    NUMBER(2),
    dname   VARCHAR2(20));

DROP TABLE em PURGE ;
CREATE TABLE em (
    emid    NUMBER(2),
    ename   VARCHAR2(20),
    dpid    NUMBER(2));

ALTER TABLE dp
ADD CONSTRAINT pk_dp_dpid PRIMARY KEY (dpid) ;

ALTER TABLE em
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_em_dp_dpid FOREIGN KEY (dpid)
REFERENCES dp (dpid) ;
```

Thanks to Mat and all.